# In and Out animation - How to combine Offset matrices Animation Node

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I would like to have two different animation in offset matrices.
**One for the In and one for the out.**
For the moment I cant have out put animation.

Thank you for your help

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by in and out animation?

Comment: @HariSreedhar If i want my object come from the right with a Z rotation  and go to the left with a Y rotation. For exemple. I have tried to mix to offset matrices but it doesn't work.